# Canonical Transformation in Quantum Phase Space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, phase-space

I am looking for a unitary representation $\hat T$ of the following canonical transformation

\begin{align}
q_1&\rightarrow q_2 &p_1&\rightarrow p_2\\
q_2 &\rightarrow -q_1&p_2&\rightarrow -p_1 
\end{align}

which is a 90°-rotation in the $(q_1,q_2)$-subspace of a 4-dim phase-space. It is therefore a point-transformation, since it does not mix positions and momenta. $\hat T$ acts as

$$
\hat T \hat q_1 \hat T^\dagger =\hat q_2 \quad \hat T \hat p_1 \hat T^\dagger =\hat p_2\\
\hat T \hat q_2 \hat T^\dagger =-\hat q_1 \quad \hat T \hat p_2 \hat T^\dagger =-\hat p_2
$$

One guess of mine is

$$
\hat T = e^{-i( p_1(q_1-q_2)-p_2(q_2+q_1))}
$$

but I do not know a way of proofing it, apart from expanding the exponentials and then computing everything brute-force, e.g. in

$$
\bigg( \sum_n^\infty \frac{i^j( p_1(q_1-q_2)-p_2(q_2+q_1))^n}{n!}\bigg) \hat q_1 \bigg( \sum_m^\infty \frac{i^m( p_1(q_1-q_2)-p_2(q_2+q_1))^m}{m!}\bigg) = \hat q_2.
$$

One would have to commute $\hat q_1$ to the left, which seems ridiculously laborious to me. Is there an easy way to find $\hat T$ for such a point-transformation? And if one must resort to guessing, is there an easy way to proof that what one has found acts in the right way?

I am deeply grateful for any help!

Comment: You will have ordering problems since not all operators in your exponential commute.

Comment: To calculate that expression, start from calculating simple and general commutator $[e^A, B]$. Since the only thing in '$A$' that does not commute with $q_1$ is $p_1$, calculation is not that cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the silly hats--everything is an operator.

Observe the obvious invariants
$$
I=q_1^2+ q_2^2, ~~~ J= p_1^2+p_2^2.
$$
Observe the hermitian operator
$$
r=q_1p_2-q_2p_1
$$
commutes with both of them, so it's worth considering its effect on your four variables,
$$
[r, q_1]=iq_2 \\  [r, q_2]=-iq_1 \\ [r, p_1]=ip_2 \\ [r, p_2]=-ip_1.
$$

But this is the precise rotations you are after a π/2 rotation for, so
$$
T= e^{-i\pi r/2}
$$
will do the trick, by the Hadamard [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#The_identity),
$$
T q_1 T^\dagger = q_1 + (-i\pi/2) [r,q_1] + \frac{1}{2!} (-i\pi/2)^2 [r,[r,q_1]]+... \\ 
 = q_1 \cos\pi/2 +q_2 \sin \pi/2= q_2,\\
T q_2 T^\dagger =- q_1, \\    T p_1 T^\dagger = p_2, \\   T p_2 T^\dagger =- p_1.
$$

Comment: Thank you a lot! That was very helpful.

Comment: This is a standard path for such things.

Comment: Could you recommend some literature, where this topic is treated in detail?

Comment: Alas, no, not sure.