# Quantum canonical transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian-formalism, commutator, phase-space

This post is very similar in content to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/591531/) one. I'm looking for a quantum implementation of the transformations

$$ x_i \to x_i + f(p) p_i, $$

$$ p_i \to h(p) p_i. $$

In these, the subindex $i$ denotes components of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{p}$; and $f(p)$ and $h(p)$ are scalar functions of $p\equiv|\mathbf{p}|$. So I'm looking for the operator $T$ implementing

$$ T x_i T^{-1} = x_i + f(p) p_i, $$

$$ T p_i T^{-1} = h(p) p_i. $$

I tried guessing an expression for $T$ inspired by the accepted answer to the [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/591531/) mentioned at the beginnig, but I couldn't work out the calculations to verify if I guessed it right. When trying to do so, I used the relation

$$ [A, e^B] = \int_0^1 ds e^{(1-s)B}[A,B]e^{sB} $$

discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52012/), but got trapped in seemly never-ending nested, multiple integrals.

**ADDENDUM**

As pointed out in the comments, the transformations above are (classicaly) canonical only for the trivial case of $h=1$. To make my question more pertinent, I rephrase it removing the required transformation for $x_i$. Therefore, I ask for the quantum implementation of the transformation $p_i \to h(p) p_i$, letting the transformation of $x_i$ be determined after requiring canonicity.

Comment: Have you first tried the trivial case of one-dimension? What have you found for *h(p)*?

Comment: I tried $T = \text{exp}(ih \mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{x})$, both for one- and three-dimensions. I end up with the same problem with multiple integrals. Considering the commutator formula above, I believe the trick is to find $B$ such that $[A,B]$ commutes with $\text{exp}(B)$, but had no luck so far. Actually, I can generate the transformation for $x_i$ setting $T=\text{exp}(iF(p))$ for some adequate $F(p)$, but it keeps $p_i$ unchanged nevertheless.

Comment: It's an xy problem. ***Have you confirmed***  for what *h(p)*  your transformation is classically canonical, i.e. it preserves Poisson Brackets?

Comment: That would be any $h(p)$ satisfying $d(ph)/dp=1$ along with $h\to1$ for $p\to0$.

Comment: So you solved for *h*?

Comment: Oh, sorry! (Lots of distractions here.) I get $h=1$, so my original question is ill-posed except for the trivial case indeed. Thanks for pointing out the way to see that!

Comment: I believe I can make my question more pertinent removing the required transformation for $x_i$.

Comment: General tip: [Let's not have posts look like revision histories](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5886/2451).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: well, to break down and modularize your problem to several technical ones,
if you stuck to one dimension and dismissed QM, so you worked in the *p*-representation where $\hat x$ is proportional to $d/dp$, and you sought the operator *T* which scales *p* by a function thereof,
$$
T p T^{-1}= p ~ h(p), 
$$
then, simply consider  Lagrange's celebrated operator, $e^{d/dk} f(k)e^{-d/dk}= f(k+1)$ :
$$
\Large T=e^{\frac{1}{k'(p)}\frac{d}{dp}} = e^{ \frac{d}{dk(p)}} ~~~\leadsto \\
TpT^{-1}= k^{-1} \Bigl ( k(p) + 1 \Bigr )= p~ h(p), ~~~\implies \\
  k(p) + 1= k(p~h(p)) ~,
$$
a functional equation specifying *k* in terms of *h*.

For example, confirm that $h(p)=\sqrt{1+1/p^2}~\leadsto k(p)=p^2$, so
$$
e^{ \frac{d}{d(p^2)}}~ p ~e^{ -\frac{d}{d(p^2)}}=e^{ \frac{d}{d(p^2)}}~\sqrt{ p^2 }~e^{ -\frac{d}{d(p^2)}}= \sqrt{1+p^2} =p ~h(p) .
$$
(This illustration does not satisfy your *h(0)=1* condition, of course, but I opted for a simple and direct one for intuitiveness, rather than a messier one that *would* satisfy it.)

Comment: Works wonderfully! Also, that's a very nice trick writing $p$ as $h^{-1}(h(p))$.